# Why doesn't sodium carbonate decompose?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

I was asked to find the hypothetical $\Delta H$ and $\Delta S$ of the decomposition of sodium carbonate and then asked to explain why it doesn't decompose.

I calculated the enthalpy and entropy change and from that I calculated the Gibbs free energy change. I was hoping to get a positive answer, but actually I got a negative answer, indicating that the process is actually spontaneous.

So is the reason that sodium carbonate doesn't decompose due to its kinetic properties, i.e. the reaction is too slow?

Comment: What is the decomposition pathway? Don't leave us in the dark! But in general if it's thermodynamically favoured but doesn't happen then it's a kinetic factor.

Comment: Your $\Delta G$ must be wrong. Sodium carbonate is thermodynamically stable.

Comment: I calculate a positive standard free energy change for the decomposition reaction.

Comment: Okay, thanks for all the help. I double checked my values I still get a negative value. The question probably gave the wrong values for the enthalpy and entropy change.

Comment: OK.  How about telling us what you got for the free energies of formation of each of the products and the reactant?

Comment: @ChesterMiller Thanks for checking it out for me. I got 319.21kJ for enthalpy change and 3.5kJ for the entropy change. But don't worry about it, they probably gave the wrong values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the values on the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_carbonate) page for sodium carbonate, the Gibbs free energy of formation is negative and thus, formation is thermodynamically preferred over decomposition at $\pu{298K}$. Your given values seem to be wrong after all.

By the way, $\Delta H$ and $\Delta S$ should be the negative of those given on that page for your case, making $\Delta G$ a positive number.